# Getting Facebook Username Into Flash

Tags: facebook, authentication, actionscript-2

I have made a Flash game that has a PHP login that's connecting with a MySQL database.
Anyway, I'm trying to make a simple app that you'll visit on Facebook and it'll automatically get your username and email from Facebook and post it into Flash through some PHP.

I have seen this on some other games such as virtual worlds like Habbo Hotel.

Firstly, is this possible in AS2 using PHP?
Secondly, how can I do this?

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Actionscript SDK fo Facebook. I think this is only for AS3 not AS2

[Actionscript SDK](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/)